# Select <td> tags in multiple tables while excluding specific tables

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following tables set up on a page:

```
<div id="schedule">
    <table class="tableListings">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tableDate">
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="tableListings">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="tableListings">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tableDate">
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="tableListings">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to set the background color **only** on the `<td>`s whose `<table>` does **not** have a `<tr>` with a class of `"tableDate"`.

How can I do that?

It would be preferable if I could do this purely with CSS, but if it would be easier (or necessary) I can use jQuery also/instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this CSS: {for simple case}

```
table tr:not(.tableDate) td{
   background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).closest('table').find('tr.tableDate').length;
}).css('background-color', '#00f');
```

Which selects all `td` elements, then filters them according to whether the closest `table` ancestor has no `tr` element with a class of `tableDate`.

If, however, you need to only if the parent `tr` has the class (not checking the whole `table` for any `tr` with that class):

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).closest('tr.tableDate');
}).css('background-color', '#00f');
```

I'm not sure (besides compatibility reasons) why you can't just use `:not(.tableDate)`, but for cross-browser compatibility:

```
td {
    background-color: #00f; /* special colour for non-.tableDate descendants */
}

.tableDate td {
    background-color: #fff; /* to override the 'special' colour for those td
                               elements that *are* within a .tableDate element */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## **CSS**

```
tr
{
 background-color:blue;   
}
.tableDate
{
     background-color:white;
}
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/X9rhS/

Answer (score 2):

If you want a CSS(3) only solution, try:

```
table.tableListings tr:not(.tableDate) td {
    background-color:#999;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sEeta/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will be help you.....

```
        table tr:not(.tableDate) td{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```